# On uninstalling the app how is the user updated in Marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, contactbuilder

The user installs the app and then opt-ins to receive push notifications. At this stage, we send the users UUID & Device ID to marketing cloud.

Scenario: If the user removes the app from the phone (but not unsubscribed) will the user be removed from the Marketing Cloud/Contact Builder  as well or how is this visible in marketing cloud?

Is it possible to see inactive app at this stage?

Answer (score 2):

On uninstalling the app, the user will still be visible in Marketing Cloud. So I presume UUID is the contact key in SFMC and will persist in SFMC (Contact Builder) even if the user uninstalls the app.

Comment: Additionally, `Is it possible to see inactive app at this stage?`; eventually, yes, the contact will be opted out if 1) the feedback service tells the MC that the device is no longer valid or 2) the failed attempts are made to send to the device.

Comment: @chandan according to your answer, does that mean that push sends will also appear in exported data for users / devices without an installed app?

Comment: @guyts Not sure. You might need to test this in the test environment.